# Use jgit to do git fetch -p

Tags: git, jgit, git-fetch

I understood that `git.fetch().setRemoveDeletedRefs(true).call()` would do the equivalent of "git fetch -p" in my program, but when I run that line, it actually deletes my master and HEAD remote refs. Running "git fetch -p" on the CLI does not.

Strangely enough, this doesn't happen on my teammates' machines. Also, while I was trying to figure out what the issue was, I set a breakpoint at that line in Intellij and used the expression evaluator to play around with different fetch() calls, and continuing the program after that didn't delete those refs, but I haven't been able to repro that since. Is this a bug in jgit, am I doing something wrong with this call, or is something wrong with my repo?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you ever figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It still happens on that particular repo, but it doesn't happen on any other that I've run this same code on. I'm guessing that it's going to remain a mystery.

Comment: Same problem here